# Laravel Model not loaded with data when trying to delete

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have one link as below:

```
    <a href='{{ route('transferDelete', $tran->transfer_id) }}'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></a>
```

It gets parsed by the following route:

```
    Route::get('delete/{transfer_id}', [TransferController::class, 'destroy'])->name('transferDelete');
```

But the destroy method in the TransferController class is empty. On the other hand, the second parameter gets the correct ID (as expected):

```
    public function destroy(Transfer $transfer, $bla)
    {
         //$transfer behaves like: $transfer = new Transfer;
         //$bla is a real id.
    }
```

Is there a way to make $transfer be pointing to transfer_id=$bla, without explicitly doing a Transfer::find($bla)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the route parameter name to the name of the typehinted parameter of the Controller method if you want Implicit Route Model Binding to take place:

```
                       v
Route::get('delete/{transfer}', ...);

                                     v 
public function destroy(Transfer $transfer, $bla)
```